# Node.js Express.js not always sending valid json

Tags: json, node.js, express, http-headers

Here is the express code

```
app.post('/v1/sessions' function(req,res){
    res.send({id:1234});
});
```

For some reason the json response comes back like this

```
OK{ id: 1234}
```

Why is the OK there?

**EDIT**

Ok so here is all of my code. I don't see where it would be sending the OK.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.post('/v1/sessions', function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.email == 'testuser@captusr.com' && req.body.password == 'testpass'){
    res.send(200, JSON.stringify({token:{id:'longstring',email:'testuser@captusr.com'}}));
  } else {
    res.send({code:403, error:"Invalid email or password"});
  }
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  if (req.method.toLowerCase() === 'options') {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: That's not all of your code.  You are sending `OK` somewhere.

Comment: When you say "the response comes back like this" exactly how are you determining this? What tool are you using. "OK" is the text that corresponding to the 200 status code, so some tools may put that there. Have you tried with `curl` or looking at the webkit development tools network tab?

Comment: I saw it in weinre when I was debugging for the android mobile browser. Everything works fine in chrome but didn't on android native. in the network view you can see the headers and sometimes the content would have the ok and sometimes it wouldn't. When it had the ok the browser thought it was mime type application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this line:

```
res.send(200, JSON.stringify({token:{id:'longstring',email:'testuser@captusr.com'}}));
```

with this and see if that solves it. Express does the 200 and JSON.stringify for you, so don't re-do it.

```
res.send({token:{id:'longstring',email:'testuser@captusr.com'}});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It has the same effect. I think now that it has to do with how I am handling the preflight option but I'm still stuck because the code I'm using seems to be working for everyone else.